# Rigorously proving convergence of a bounded sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose that there is a function $ a_{n} $ which is real and bounded.

Given some $ k \in \mathbf{N}$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_{kn} -k(a_{n})) =0$$

How can I rigorously say that $a_{n}$ is convergent?

I tried to say that given it is bounded we know that the sequence does not tend to infinity and by the statement given to us we know the sequence converges to some value. Hence the sequence must converge. However, this does not seem rigorous enough for a proof.

Comment: i think you must exclude $k=1$, no ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $k\geq2$ is integer. Let $M=\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|$ which exists as the sequence is bounded. If we can show $M=0$, then it implies $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

Choose an $\epsilon>0$. We can find a $N$ such that for all $n>N$

$$|a_{kn}-ka_n|<\epsilon$$

and by iteratively using this, we get

$$|a_{k^ln}-k^la_n|<\epsilon\sum_{i=0}^{l-1}k^i=\epsilon\frac{k^l-1}{k-1}$$

But now we also know that some $m>n$ exists such that $|M-a_m|<\epsilon$. This implies

\begin{align*}
|M-a_{k^lm}|&\geq|a_m-a_{k^lm}|-|a_m-M|\\
&>|k^la_m-a_m|-|a_{k^lm}-k^la_m|-\epsilon\\
&>(k^l-1)|a_m|-\epsilon\frac{k^l-1}{k-1}-\epsilon\\
&>(k^l-1)(M-\epsilon)-\epsilon\frac{k^l-1}{k-1}-\epsilon\\
&=M(k^l-1)-\epsilon\left(\frac{k^{l+1}-1}{k-1}\right)
\end{align*}

assuming $M\neq0$, we can choose $\epsilon$ small enough and $l$ big enough (I'll leave this detail for you to check!), and we see that $a_{k^lm}$ grows like $k^lM$, which contradicts the bounded assumption. Hence $M=0$ and we're done

Answer (score 0):

For $k > 1$, we prove that there is a unique limit point for $a_n$. Suppose that there was a nonzero limit point $L$ of $a_n$. Then, take $a_{n_i}$ as a subsequence that converges to that limit. Then, we can find $a_{kn_i} - ka_{n_i} \to 0$. This implies that $a_{kn_i} \to kL$, and by doing this recursively, we have $a_{k^jn_i} \to k^jL$, and arrive at a contradiction: that $a_n$ is unbounded.

For $k = 1$, $(-1)^n$ serves as a counterexample.